# Show a pyramid based on number input

Tags: c#

I'm currently stuck on this problem the goal is to be able to print out a pyramid depending on the input number.
Ex: input = 3

It should look like this:

```
 1
23
```

I'm able to make it work with some numbers but it doesn't work with other inputs.
The current logic that I follow is by dividing the input by 2 then add the remainder to the next one to be divided.

```
Example input: 10
10 / 2 = 5 remainder: 0
5 / 2 = 2 remainder: 1
2 + 1 (previous remainder)/ 2 = 1 remainder: 1
1

Whereas it would look like this:
5
2
2
1

The rules of the pyramid that I'm trying to make only needs to have one or two differences per row.
That's why I'll be needing to deduct 1 from 5 and add it to the next one:
4
3
2
1

Thus having pyramid like this: 10
****
***
**
*
```

The problem is this approach isn't applicable on other inputs and I'm having a hard time on finding a different approach for this.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for your example, although it might be improved to detect whenever a number is not suitable to print a piramid.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a number:");
            int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            List<List<string>> piramid = new List<List<string>>();
            int rowNumber = 1, dotsCount = 0;

            while (dotsCount < input)
            {
                List<string> row = new List<string>();
                for (int i = 1; i <= rowNumber && dotsCount < input; i++)
                {
                    row.Add("*");
                    dotsCount++;
                }
                piramid.Add(row);
                rowNumber++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Piramid");
            Print(piramid);

            Console.WriteLine("Piramid (inverted)");
            PrintInverted(piramid);
        }

    }

    static void Print(List<List<string>> piramid)
    {
        foreach (var item in piramid)
        {
            item.ForEach(Console.Write);
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
    }

    static void PrintInverted(List<List<string>> piramid)
    {
        for (int i = piramid.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            List<string> item = piramid[i];
            item.ForEach(Console.Write);
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It helped me with the core stuff needed now I added more things that will handle if it is not a triangular number (cannot form pyramids).